# C++ struct access violation

Tags: c++, struct

I have the following struct defined in the header file:

```
typedef struct _wfs_cdm_physicalcu
{
    LPSTR           lpPhysicalPositionName;
    CHAR            cUnitID[5];
    ULONG           ulInitialCount;
    ULONG           ulCount;
    ULONG           ulRejectCount;
    ULONG           ulMaximum;
    USHORT          usPStatus;
    BOOL            bHardwareSensor;
} WFSCDMPHCU, * LPWFSCDMPHCU;
```

And in my code file I try to use it like this:

```
LPWFSCDMPHCU cdm_physical_cass;
strcpy(cdm_physical_cass->cUnitID, "1234");
cdm_physical_cass->lpPhysicalPositionName = "DISP1";
cdm_physical_cass->bHardwareSensor = FALSE;
cdm_physical_cass->ulInitialCount = 100;
```

The code compiles fine, however I get access violation on that strcpy so I think the struct is not initialized properly.
Any thoughts?

Comment: next time produce a real MCVE. Then you'll at least know that not `strcpy` is the real culprit. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hungarian notation horror :-P. Also don't use `_` as a prefix. That's reserved for standard implementations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cdm_physical_cass` is not initialized/allocated.
You have to call

```
LPWFSCDMPHCU cdm_physical_cass = new WFSCDMPHCU;
```

Better would be to use smart pointers (as `std::unique_ptr`).

Comment: Thanks, it worked.
I tried this earlier but like this:
LPWFSCDMPHCU cdm_physical_cass = new LPWFSCDMPHCU;
What is the difference?

Comment: `LPWFSCDMPHCU` is `WFSCDMPHCU*`.

Answer (score 1):

`LPWFSCDMPHCU cdm_physical_cass;` is not a struct it's a pointer to a struct of type `WFSCDMPHCU`. You must allocate memory for the struct pointed to by `cdm_physical_cass`. The function `WFMAllocateBuffer` is recommended for that.

Answer (score 0):

Since LPWFSCDMPHCU is a pointer and not a struct , you'll need to allocate memory(malloc or new depending of the language) for that pointer ( LPWFSCDMPHCU ) then you can use the fields.